# "535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure" with postfix and dovecot sasl authentication

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot, smtp-auth

I'm testing remote smtp login on a server and keep getting `535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure` errors in the syslog and mail.log. Postfix is configured to use system user names and passwords.

I generated a user name and password with `perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("username");'` and `perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("password");'`

I am logging into the server with `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect email.example.com:587` and using the `auth login` to input the user name and password.

I've turned on dovecot debugging but not seeing much in logs other than the authentication failure message.

Postfix main.cf:

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
#smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
myhostname = email.example.org
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = example.com
home_mailbox = Maildir/
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, email.example.com, ip-172-30-0-39.ec2.internal, localhost.ec2.internal, localhost, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

dovecot:

```
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}

service auth {
  # auth_socket_path points to this userdb socket by default. It's typically
  # used by dovecot-lda, doveadm, possibly imap process, etc. Users that have
  # full permissions to this socket are able to get a list of all usernames and
  # get the results of everyone's userdb lookups.
  #
  # The default 0666 mode allows anyone to connect to the socket, but the
  # userdb lookups will succeed only if the userdb returns an "uid" field that
  # matches the caller process's UID. Also if caller's uid or gid matches the
  # socket's uid or gid the lookup succeeds. Anything else causes a failure.
  #
  # To give the caller full permissions to lookup all users, set the mode to
  # something else than 0666 and Dovecot lets the kernel enforce the
  # permissions (e.g. 0777 allows everyone full permissions).
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    #user =
    #group =
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
}

service auth-worker {
  # Auth worker process is run as root by default, so that it can access
  # /etc/shadow. If this isn't necessary, the user should be changed to
  # $default_internal_user.
  #user = root
}

service dict {
  # If dict proxy is used, mail processes should have access to its socket.
  # For example: mode=0660, group=vmail and global mail_access_groups=vmail
  unix_listener dict {
    #mode = 0600
    #user =
    #group =
  }
}
```

Comment: I can log in with imap remotely without issue. It's just smtp giving me the problem. I'll post more of config when I get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was able to get authentication working by adding the following lines to the postfix main.cf config file:

```
 smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
 smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
 smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Comment: Note that by adding it to `main.cf` unprefixed you are offering sasl on all ports - you might wish to tune `smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options` & `smtpd_sasl_security_options` to prevent accepting plain passwords via unencrypted connections.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yeah, I will be going back through these settings to tighten things up as much as possible for sure. Goal for now is to just establish a working baseline.